# Statistical support to aid setting weights in a simple function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, statistical-power

I'd like to create some consensus scoring function that incorporates two independent scoring functions $f_1$ and $f_2$.  These functions rank items $i$ where there are $i=20,000$ items.

$C_i = (f_1 * w_1) + (f_2 * w_2)$

While $f_1$ considers all items, there is a constraint on $f_2$, where it only considers (ranks) 4,000 of the possible 20,000 items.  Information in $f_2$ is still valuable because in the end, the only non-zero scores tend to be in the top 500 results.  $C_1 ... C_{500}$ is a list of items recommended to the user.

Are there any sample size or power methods that I can use to aid in setting my weights?  I'm assuming that $f_1$ should have more power given the larger sample size, and thus be given more weight.  First post, thank you for reading.

Comment: No answers, this is my first question on the site, so I may not be wording it properly or providing enough context.  Would it make sense to make the weight proportionate to the number of items the function considers? In the example: w1 would equal 1.0 and w2 would equal 0.2.